# AWS Swift sudden crash

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

App Crashing before coming to `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.

It was working fine before, but don't know why suddenly crashing.
Got this trace.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '`defaultServiceConfiguration` is `nil`. You need to set it before using this method.'

Comment: Dear down voter could please explain the reason?

Comment: You need to post more code. There must be something you are calling if you get the error.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and do a complete rebuild?

Comment: It is crashing before calling `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` , so no need to post code.

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with your code then the problem is in the project configuration. You should use git so you could go back and see what you have broken. Have you tried to clean the project and run pod install again?

Comment: Are trying to run in the simulator or a device? 32-bit or 64-bit device?

Comment: device,yes cleaned it.

Comment: @Tapani got issue solved, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the exact issue, but creating `AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper` object when need and not after class declaration solved my issue.

Defined just before it's use:

```
let dynamoDBObjectMapper:AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()
```

Comment: What you mean by "after class declaration"? Did you init some property with the value returned by defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper? If so, you should have post your code here.

Comment: I was doing like this:

`class myClass{ initHere-dynamoDBObj}`

But when tried only initialising when using it, did the trick.